# Can I fully tag a non tagged PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, itext

Currently, we have an application that uses SSRS to render PDFs. Unfortunately, these PDFs do not come tagged.

We are looking to post-process the PDF so that it has the tags and structure to satisfy accessibility requirements provided by AODA and Section 508.

Mostly, the outputs consist of tables, and charts.

Is this possible with ITextSharp?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: Amedee's answer is correct and incorrect at the same time. It is correct in the sense that you can use iText to tag an existing PDF in an automated way. It is incorrect in the sense that you can't use iText to *correctly* tag an existing PDF in an automated way. For instance: I could define all content as an Artefact and the PDF would pass all automated accessibility test. However, that PDF wouldn't pass any test done by a human being. Making a PDF accessible means that you have to add semantic structure to a PDF. That needs to be done by a human.

Comment: Your question is all wrong. In my opinion, you will get a much better result if you'd stop using SSRS and use iText to create the PDFs as Tagged PDFs directly. Tagged PDF is PDF + semantic information. You have that semantic information *before* you create the PDF with SSRS, but that semantic information is lost *after* that PDF is created. You can't expect software to restore that lost information. It takes a human to interpret the content of the PDF. If you want a machine to replace that human, you either need to build a sophisticated AI system, or fool your customer by producing bad tags.

Comment: So please tell your boss to drop SSRS and to do the right thing. If he isn't interesting in doing the right thing and if he insists that you ask us to fool the system, then I suggest that you do yourself a favor and start looking for a new boss.

Comment: (question flagged as too broad)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, that was the confirmation I was looking for.