# How can I add accessibility tagging to non-tagged PDF with iTextSharp using PDF content nodes?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, accessibility

How can I add accessibility tagging to non-tagged PDF with iTextSharp using PDF content nodes?

Per [Can I fully tag a non tagged PDF using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758217/can-i-fully-tag-a-non-tagged-pdf-using-itextsharp), I know we can't get perfect tagging compared to a human or tagging the PDF as its being created (the best options), but what about taking the PDF content objects and just doing a "best effort" semantic tagging to improve readability?

The basic principle I would think could be to sort all PDF content objects left to right, top to bottom, and then say for a text node, create simple P tags in that order so that they're spoken at least.  If there are form objects intermixed, then tag those as well. Obviously if its all paths and artifacts, there isn't much you can do with it, but plenty of PDFs have text nodes.  I can't rely on Adobe Reader trying to determine reading order.

For example, [the content structure of a PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0dyW.png) is a simple example that has Text content nodes that could be tagged.  We can't control the source PDF generation, but need to manipulate the PDF by adding headers/footers, etc and want it all tagged together.

How can we achieve this with iTextSharp?  We have the commercial version 5.5.10.0 version.

For example, abcpdf has a function called [MakeAccessible](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/8-abcpdf.operations/c-accessibilityoperation/1-methods/makeaccessible.htm) that attempts this and works fairly well. However, we want to use iTextSharp.

Comment: _We have the commercial version 5.5.10.0 version._ -> Please contact iText directly. You have a support contract, which means guaranteed response. An answer isn't guaranteed on SO.

Comment: I would say it depends on what you are trying to meet. You could do half a job. I suppose the PDF would be ok for someone who is half blind then.